# SQL Connection Compile Errors

Tags: c#

I just got a new PC and am trying to remember how to set everything back up as needed, but am epic failing.  I want to run this simple piece of code below, but have been hammered with compile errors.  can someone be so kind to point out what I need to do to remove all of these compile errors?

```
using (SQLConnnection conn = new SQLConnection(connectionStringSQL)
{
  conn.Open();
  Using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1");
  conn.Close();
}
```

LIST of compile errors ----

1) 'SQL.SQLConnection': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
2) 'SQL.SQLConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
3) 'SQL.SQLConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Open' and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of type 'SQL.SQLConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4) The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments
5) cannot convert from 'SQL.SQLConnection' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'
6) The name 'command' does not exist in the current context
7) 'SQL.SQLConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'SQL.SQLConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Change this Using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1"); with Using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1")) {}

Comment: the good news is, it has nothing to do with getting a new pc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringSQL))
{
     conn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1"))
     {

     }
     conn.Close();
}
```

1. Not `SQLConnnection` -> `SqlConnection`
2. Not `Using` -> `using`
3. Don't forget to close parenthesis for `using`.
4. Don't put semicolon after `using` `using(...); <----`

Comment: I tried your suggested tweak and am still getting the compile errors?

Comment: I'm not surprised but you don't need an answer. you need to learn C# syntax.

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions See his new edit. Now it should work

Answer (score 3):

If you read the 5th error cleary , you would see that. You are using

```
 using SQL.SQLConnection;
```

But you should use

```
 using System.Data.Sqlclient.Sqlconnection;
```

Check your namespace header or specified it. I can read this from ther error. Besides, you are missing a bracket. See selman22 answer.

Comment: Actually it's 1,2,3,5,7 but 5 is the most specific

Answer (score 1):

since you are using `using`  you dont need to close the connection , it will close, moreover, since you dont execute your query:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringSQL))
{
     conn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1"))
     {
                    cmd1 = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd1.CommandText = command;
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

     }

}
```

though probably you want to execute a `DataReader` but it is up to you